# Laravel Sanctum re-calling the /login route on any React actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, cookies, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to create simple SPA using Laravel Sanctum and ReactJS. I've faced an issue when I do any of action in my frontend part my cookies are re-rendered which make my `/logout` path useless since even if I see a `CSRF token mismatch.` message in my console I still can access my backend part.

Here are some screenshots to understand the issue correctly:

1. There are no cookies added yet, I'm calling my `/login` route to be authorized so I can use my protected routes (ignore the `/dashboard` route call, it's blocked in my `cors.php` and it's just a redirect):
   [image: Logging in]
2. Now I can access my `/api/cars` route to get all the cars from my DB:
   [image: Get all cars]
3. Now I want to logout so I don't have an access to my `/api/cars`. I'm calling an `/logout` route which will make my current token invalid:
   [image: Logout]
4. And now if I go back to `/api/cars` I can still access this route, even if my token is invalid
   [image: Access api cars route]

So as I mentioned the problem is that as soon as I do any of the action I can clearly see that my `laravel_session` and `XSRF-TOKEN` cookies are updated, but from the console logs I can't see ant `/login` routes called after logout so it's really confusing me.

I really think that the problem is in my components rendering but since I don't call the routes that I don't need I don't really understand what is the issue. I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Here are all of my React components:

App.jsx:

```
import './App.css';

import {useState} from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Route,
    Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <Header />
                    <main className="main">
                        <div className="main__container">
                            <Routes>
                                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                            </Routes>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Home.jsx:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

import HomeLayout from "../layouts/HomeLayout";
import Search from "../components/Search";
import Car from "../components/Car";
import Pagination from "../components/Pagination";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

export default function Home() {
    const [cars, setCars] = useState({});
    const [error, setError] = useState('');
    const [pageUrl, setPageUrl] = useState('http://localhost/api/cars');
    const [loadingStatus, setLoadingStatus] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(pageUrl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    setError(response.statusText);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                setCars(data);
                setLoadingStatus(false);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, [pageUrl]);

    return (
        <HomeLayout>
            {loadingStatus
                ? (<span>Loading...</span>)
                : (<>
                        <Search pageUrl={pageUrl} setPageUrl={setPageUrl}/>
                        {error ?
                            <span>{error}</span>
                            :
                            cars.data === undefined || cars.data.length === 0
                                ? <div className={'search__no-result'}>
                                    <h3>No cars</h3>
                                </div>
                                : (<>
                                    <div className={'car__wrapper'}>
                                        {cars.data.map((car) => (
                                            <Car key={car.id} car={car}/>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>
                                    <Pagination links={cars.meta.links} setPageUrl={setPageUrl}/></>)}
                    </>
                )}
        </HomeLayout>
    )
}
```

HomeLayout.jsx:

```
import Header from "../components/Header";

export default function HomeLayout({children}) {
    return (
        <>
            <main className={'main'}>
                <div className={'main__container'}>
                    {children}
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

Car.jsx:

```
export default function Car({car}) {
    return (
        <div className={'car'}>
            {car.images.map((image) => (
                <img className={'car__image'} key={image.id} src={image.image_url} alt={car.name} />
            ))}
            <div className={'car__description'}>
                <span><b>ID:</b> {car.id}</span>
                <span><b>NAME:</b> {car.name}</span>
                <span><b>VIN:</b> {car.vin}</span>
                <span><b>MANUFACTURER:</b> {car.manufacturer}</span>
                <span><b>MODEL:</b> {car.model}</span>
                <span><b>YEAR:</b> {car.year}</span>
                <span><b>COLOR:</b> {car.color}</span>
                <span><b>MILEAGE:</b> {car.mileage}</span>
                <span><b>PRICE:</b> {car.price}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Login.jsx:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import axios from "axios";
import {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const email = useRef(null);
    const password = useRef(null);

    function login(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch("http://localhost/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: "include",
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)

                fetch("http://localhost/login", {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        email: email.current.value,
                        password: password.current.value,
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')),
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={(event) => login(event)}>
                <input type="email" ref={email}/>
                <input type="password" ref={password}/>
                <button type={'submit'}>Submit</button>
            </form>
            <button onClick={() => navigate('/')}>Home</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Header.jsx:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    function logout(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        fetch('http://localhost/logout', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            credentials: 'include',
        })
            .then(response => {
                navigate('/login');
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };

    return (
        <header>
            <div className={'header__container'}>
                <div className={'header__content'}>
                    <div className={'header__nav'}>
                        {Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN') ?
                            (<>
                                <Link
                                    className={'header__nav-link logout'}
                                    method="post" as="button"
                                    onClick={(event) => logout(event)}
                                >
                                    Logout
                                </Link>
                            </>)
                            :
                            (<Link
                                className={'header__nav-link'}
                                to={'/login'}
                            >
                                Login
                            </Link>)
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    )
}
```

Pagination.jsx

```
export default function Pagination({links, setPageUrl}) {
    const decodeHtmlEntities = (html) => {
        const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
        textarea.innerHTML = html;
        return textarea.value;
    };

    return (
        <div className={`pagination`}>
            {links.map((link) => (
                <button className={`pagination__page ${link.active ? 'active' : ''}`} key={link.label}
                        onClick={() => setPageUrl(link.url)}>
                    {decodeHtmlEntities(link.label)}
                    {link.i}
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Search.jsx:

```
import {useRef} from "react";

export default function Search({setPageUrl}) {
    const name = useRef(null);

    function submitSearch(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        setPageUrl(`http://localhost/api/cars/search?name=${name.current.value}`);
    }

    return (
        <div className={'search__container'}>
            <form className={'search__form'} onSubmit={(event) => submitSearch(event)}>
                <input placeholder={'Search by name'} type="text" name={'search'} ref={name}/>
                <button type={'submit'}>Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Use Interiajs i don't even know when last time i use this kind of setting now it is just so easy https://www.inertiajs.com/ why make thing complicate.

Comment: I know about inertia but my goal is to create 2 separate projects and use API to speak between them

Comment: add it on your front only then

Comment: You probably going to use some form module only